# What’s the cost of Road tolls Calais to Copenhagenby car?

Tags: france, driving, uk-citizens, tolls, copenhagen

Travelling by car from Calais to Copenhagen and would appreciate advice  re cost of road tolls from anyone who’s done this recently.

Comment: Which route do you plan on driving? Have you looked at https://www.sixt.co.uk/toll-roads/europe/

Comment: It can be free, if you select your route carefully. But that might mean ferry costs in Denmark.

Comment: @Willeke 'Might mean'? How can you get to Copenhagen without paying either toll for a bridge or a ferry ticket?

Comment: Google Maps will advise you of tolls, though it won't tell you how much they are. However, its fastest suggested route only has one "toll", which is actually a ferry: it shouldn't be hard to find out what that costs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends obviously on your route. You should be ok in France, Netherlands and Germany.

In Denmark you need to get to Zealand, which is an island. You can take either the Puttgarden/Rodby ferry from Germany or go the long way around over the Storebælt bridge. The bridge is cheaper but also a considerable detour.

Cost depends on vehicle and number of passengers. You can look it up at  https://www.storebaelt.dk/english/toll-charges and https://www.directferries.com/puttgarden_rodby_ferry.htm?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&dfgeoo=true&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI_f3T6_Gv4wIVjZ-fCh39AgJWEAAYASAAEgKUUPD_BwE

Comment: Really appreciate these links; excellent advice. It looks like a lengthy drive!